# Reverting changes to older commits from detached head of master

Tags: git

My origin/master somehow got some unwanted merges. Hence, I was trying to revert the origin/master into the previous commit. While doing so I checkout the remote HEAD and ran `$ git reset --hard fcced95d565a4e54e81f15d1efeab5fdf7a483ca`. Then I was trying to basically push this commit and ran `$ git push -f origin master`. However, doing this actually brought the origin/master to the state that my local was in and that is way behind where I wanted to revert the commit to for my DEATACHED HEAD OF master. How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't already also overwritten your local `master` branch, you can just try the following:

```
git checkout master
git push --force origin master
```

This assumes that your local `master` is alive and well, and untainted by what you have done to its remote counterpart.  If you *also* nuked your local `master` branch, then you would need to do more work.

First, we can use a tool called the reflog to find the commit which was the previous HEAD of `master`, before you overwrote it.  Type `git reflog`, which will pull up a list of commits having recent activity on the heads of the branches in your repo.  You will have to sift through this list to find the previous HEAD commit from `master`.  Stack Overflow and the Git manual well cover how to navigate the reflog.

Then, once you have the SHA-1 hash of the commit, just do the following from `master`:

```
git reset --hard <SHA-1 of previous HEAD>
```

This will reset local `master` to the correct commit.  Then do another force push to overwrite the remote branch:

```
git push --force origin master
```